# Send encrypted Mail to LotusNotes from Intranet WebApp

Tags: c#, .net, email, encryption, lotus-notes

Can someone give me a starting point on how to send an encypted mail from my C# .NET Application to a Lotus Notes inbox (in the company intranet)?

I requested a certificate and Notes User from our support.

But now I'm stuck. I read through this [guide](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2009/10/02/sending-encrypted-email-with-c), and implemented the code but know the mails in my inbox do not have any content, but just a file named `smime.p7m`. So I am generally unsure if this is the right method.

Can you give me a hint to a tutorial or tell me the steps I need to do?
Or is the linked guide generally right and I goofed something up? In this case please leave a comment an I'll add my code.

Thank you very much in advance!

**UPDATE 1 (26.08.16):**

Here is what I'm now at so far:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.services.companyname");
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("NOTESUSER","password");
smtp.Send(message);
```

In Notes itself I ticket the checkbox for "Send my mails encrypted". The thought behind it was the following:
I assumed this way the Notes User passes the credentials to the Smtp Server and uses the usersettings.

The eMails get delivered, but are not encrypted.

Comment: The .p7m file is the encrypted content. Try sending it to the Notes user.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz This is what I have in the mail inbox of the NotesUser

Comment: In that case, there's something wrong with the MIME headers of the message that you are sending, causing Notes to fail to recognize it as an encrypted message. You need to compare the MIME source of your message to the MIME source of a correctly formatted encrypted message. Do you have an available non-Notes mail client configured to send encrypted messages that you can use to send a message to the Notes user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is what I finally did:

```
Domino.NotesSession nSession = new Domino.NotesSession();
nSession.Initialize("secretpassword"); //password for the Notes User
Domino.NotesDatabase nDatabase = nSession.GetDatabase("SERVER", "names"); //Server and location of the names.nfs file
Domino.NotesDocument nDocument = nDatabase.CreateDocument();
NotesStream nStream;
nDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", tmp.Subject);
nBody = nDocument.CreateMIMEEntity();                
nStream = nSession.CreateStream();
nStream.WriteText(tmp.Body);
nBody.SetContentFromText(nStream , "text/HTML;charset=UTF-8", MIME_ENCODING.ENC_IDENTITY_7BIT);
nDocument.EncryptOnSend = true;
nDocument.Send(false, user.INS_EMAIL);
```

This creates a Notes Session with the latest Notes User logged in. So you install the Notes client on the Server, log in with the user and it works so far.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try and break down things a bit further. What about sending an encrypted email from a basic mail client like Thunderbird to a person who will open it in her Notes client ?

The fundamental thing is that the recipient must have a private key symetric to the public key you used for encryption. In normal use, Domino does this very well as it comes with its own two-factors PKI : users can't sign in without their private key, which is stored on their workstation in a tiny (~3 ko) file named something like `hername.id` or `user.id`. The corresponding public key is for all to see, as it should, in the Domino Directory (`names.nsf`)

While based on standard RSA stuff, those usual pairs of keys are managed and deployed in ways very specific to Domino.

Now, it is perfectly possible for a user to import a private key issued by a third-party certification authority. I don't have the exact procedure at hand right now buy you'll find it in the `help.nsf` available to any Notes client.

But I wonder. You are inside the intranet, which means that [you do have access to the Domino Directory](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-msnet/), thus to the usual public key of the recipient. Your application will probably need its own `user.id` and it's more than likely that you'll need to have the `1352` hole punched in various firewalls. By the way, if it helps to alleviate any concern, by virtue of the aformentioned native PKI, it is very easy to encrypt communications on port 1352 from end to end.

Another option is as follow. The Domino server is also a web server. Sometimes this option is activated, sometimes not. If it is, or if you can make it happen, the directory is available as a web application. Zooming in on the public key of a user would require some tinkering and some HTML parsing but *should* be doable.

One last one for the road, although you may not like it : Domino is a very good platform for intranet applications, be it of the client-server persuasion or of the HTTP creed.

Comment: I cannot use a email-client, since LotusNotes is the email client of my company. And I'm trying to encrypt the emails that are send by my application (auto-generated). What I really need would be the basic steps I need to setup this procedure, maybe with some code snippets. I really have little to no experience concerning encryption & Lotus Notes.

Comment: Then do it from home. My point is it would give you a chance to experiment with a simple case and gain understanting of the process you want to automate. 

If I may utter a more general comment, cryptography is not trivial, even moreso in Domino, whose tight security is there from Notes version 1.

Comment: Then do it from home. My point is it would give you a chance to experiment with a simple case and gain understanting of the process you want to automate. 

An even simpler test case, but one that in your case could give you some insight, would be to send an encrypted mail from Notes to Notes and try to understand what's going on.

If I may utter a more general comment, cryptography is not trivial, even moreso in Domino, whose tight security is there from Notes version 1.

Comment: I may be wrong, but my feeling is that you won't make it with basic steps and code snippets. Ideally you would work with the Domino admin and someone knwoledgeable in the field of SMTP encryption. By the way I've just realized that from the start I assume that your app sends mail using the SMTP protocol, if I'm wrong please correct.

Comment: My biggest problem is the lack of the latter: "someone knowledgeable in the field of SMTP encryption". But yes, you assumed right. And all of your advise is very sensible, it is just the lack of time and pressing business needs ...